# Increasingly growing vertical lines on my laptop screen (Dell Inspiron 7520 SE)

Tags: display, hardware-failure, lcd, dell-inspiron, led

I've had these 2 vertical lines since yesterday. Their length have doubled since then ! Would someone please help identifying the problem and the solution ?
I've had this laptop for around 2 years now

I uploaded my images to my [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2SnctckunwfnNWbFpvTGNpVER4WTFxb0FjX0JIeWxVZEpROG94VDZPU0ZBZVF4SXBVMTQ). Kindly have a look at them. I'm very sorry but I'm not sure what type of screen is it, whether its LED or LCD ! This is the [product's page](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15r-se-7520/pd) on the Dell's website.

Comment: Looks like dead pixel to me... still  under warranty hopefully?

Comment: @Darius, no :(, how bad can this get ?

Comment: I don't know. It may just stuck as it is and won't get worse. Not much you can do unless you want to contact dell and ask them. They can fix / replace the monitor but out of warranty they most likely will charge you for it. Try calling them and explain to them anyway and see how you go. Sometimes if it is a defect they may chose to fix even out of warranty. Good luck.